# How to add a row before first row of every group in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, row

I want to add a row before every Customer group in my table which is ordered using the Customer ID. Is it possible to do so using FIRST_VALUE() or there is some other technique?

Comment: Can you add sample data and result

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table's structure, and what exactly Customer group means. as it is now, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: As you are new to stakoverflow welcome and read this for batter response to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what is the purpose of this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @customer table (id int, name varchar(500));

insert into @customer (id, name) values
  (1, 'Client1'),
  (2, 'Client2'),
  (3, 'Client3'),
  (4, 'Client4');


select
  c.id, c.name, 2 ord
from
  @customer c
union all
select
  c.id, 'some new value before', 1 ord
from
  @customer c
order by
  id, ord
;
```